# Job asking for bank email and password

Tags: new-job

I just got a job offer with a mobile entertainment network company. But it doesn't feel right with what they are asking. They want my account information. But they also want my user name and password to my account. I never had a job ask that before. Should I back away?

Comment: Did they interview you before they gave you the job offer? If not, then that's another sign that it's a scam. "If it's too good to be true, it probably isn't."

Comment: Out of interest, what country are you in (and is the supposed job offer based in the same country, or elsewhere?)

Comment: What is a “mobile entertainment network company”?!

Comment: Being asked for password is *always* a sign that something is completely wrong. Nobody else other than you needs your password. Moreover the admins of the service itself don't need your password to access your account, since they can do so from the backend, and they have other means of authenticating you.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420/321647

Comment: Giving them this is probably a violation of the terms and conditions of your bank (to which you have presumably agreed), and would probably make you liable for any fraudulent action taken.

Comment: The bank attributes all transactions done through your password to your person-  how does this company plan to repudiate a charge of fraudulent transaction  by impersonating you through the password - You must ask this to your future employers, out of sheer concern towards them. Note : you are not sharing an apprehension - but only seeking details of the repudiation mechanism which shall be employed.

Comment: Intimate the employers that - The bank has warned you not to share the password with any one - as  much as you would like to comply to your employers - sadly you are bound by contract to the bank.; however you have forwarded to the bank a copy of this request; for whatever best can be done.

Comment: To echo what @JohnB.Lambe said, it is likely against the T&C. More than that, some regions at trying to make it illegal to share your password with someone else. It is your password. It must not be shared with your employer. As others have commented, seek a lawyer and/or law enforcement and break all contact with this company.

Comment: My answer to them would be "what account" and "what password"?  All 200 of them, though, at the very least, I'd like them to try to justify 'why'.  Get them "off script" and they'll have a melt down -- like the repair scam that called me and told me my computer was sending out traffic to their server that indicated it was infected.  When I asked them for the IP or name of my computer, they choked -- apparently they couldn't give me such 'private' information...  *idiots*

Comment: The intention of a such a request seems so obvious and unambiguous...kinda makes me paranoid of the question being used as a staging ground to gauge reactions.

Answer (score 574):

***Scam.*** They have absolutely no justification for requesting your password.

Don't back away. ***Run!*** And report them to the service they contacted you through, so they can be kicked off it. And to the appropriate government offices; in the US, information about that can be found at https://www.usa.gov/stop-scams-frauds

(The FTC in particular has been going after scam artists fairly actively in the past year. I still wish they could be funded well enough to do that properly, but it helps.)

Comment: Just to add to this, you really wouldn't be passing up any opportunity anyway. Any tech based company that would genuinely require this (and I very much doubt it) wouldn't be able to tell their arse from their elbow, let alone run a successful business.

Answer (score 78):

The only thing even remotely close to this that I have ever seen is getting clearance on a government or  military project/sub contractor, and they don't ask for your password (or account name). They may ask you to print out a statement, or to have the bank fill out a form (that would contain account balances and average transaction sizes), but I have never seen, even in that case, a request for a username and password.

This is an obvious scam. Even if your setting up direct deposit (some employers do require direct deposit these days) they only ask for routing numbers and account numbers.

Comment: The institutions that **REALLY** (legally) need to see your banking info are also the ones that don't need to ask login details to get the info they need.

Answer (score 56):

You should contact the police. In some cases law enforcement may ask you to go along with the request but using a new account set up by the bank to help get these criminals prosecuted.

Comment: cool, never heard of that before

Answer (score 14):

I know of no (and there is no) legitimate use or need for a bank logon and password.

An employer can legitimately make use of a bank account number for direct deposit; and I have heard directly from one employee that their employer requires a bank account for payments; but employers set that up without your bank logon and password.

Comment: > "and I have heard directly from one employee that their employer requires a bank account for payments" I've never heard of a company that _doesn't_ do this, how else would people get paid?

Comment: @Tom some countries still pay their workers using *checks* (like UK *cheques*)

Comment: @ChrisH Oh right! TIL :) Must be annoying having to nip to the bank at the end of each month and waiting for the cheque to clear.  Do the banks not get really busy with everyone paying in their cheques?

Comment: @Tom I suspect so -- I'm in the UK and have only been paid for normal employment by cheque a handful of times (usually the first month, once the last).  I know I can pay in cheques by post, but I don't know if that's a common option in the US.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I've been to the bank (in the US) on a Friday when most people get paid, and there was quite a line. This was a few years ago and is probably not as common now with direct deposit becoming more ubiquitous. I'm sure it still happens though.

Comment: @SethR When I first worked in the late 90s, salaries were already paid directly into bank accounts for the majority of people here in the UK.  It seems surprising the the US is so far behind on this.

Comment: I have had direct deposit set up on my paycheck for quite some time.  I believe my current employer actually now requires the direct deposit set up, but since I already was set up, I didn't pay much attention to it.

Comment: @Tom: Yeah, much like most things financial, our PAYE system is way ahead of the norm over the pond!

Comment: It's also the case in the UK that funds from payroll cheques are often made available straight away (and certanly before normal clearing) because the likelihood of bouncing is low -- and if it does bounce then the bank is likely to have to be helpful in sorting out the resultant financial problems anyway.

Comment: Use of direct deposit is certainly increasing in the US, but definitely not universal. Fortunately, the line at the bank problem on pay days is mitigated by ATMs that directly process check deposits by scanning them on the spot, and smart-phone camera based deposits, where you don't visit a bank facility or machine at all. We've got a lot of dumb stuff to accommodate the fact that we still use checks/cheques heavily.

Comment: My first ever job out of school in 1977 already used direct bank transfers for salary. I haven't had a job since that didn't. Giving your account details; sort code, a/c number & name is standard practise in the UK. None of that info will allow anyone to access the account, only pay to it. Passwords & PINs on the other hand are an entirely different matter :/

Answer (score -3):

I would give them fake data and record them while they are asking and taking your account.
Then I would head on the next police station and use the recording as an evidence to send them to jail.

And for people into legalese, see  [2nd U.S. Circuit Court of Appeals](https://www.wired.com/2010/08/covert-iphone-audio-recording).

Comment: Depending on where you live, it is often illegal to record someone without their consent. This would only get you in trouble as well.

Comment: @DavidK: In fact, depending on where you live. According to the [2nd U.S. Circuit Court of Appeals](https://www.wired.com/2010/08/covert-iphone-audio-recording) you can for legitimate use and in most democracies it should be so. Not to mention the number of cases, where the police itself instructs people to do so.

Comment: You should ask the police _first_, then do so on their request if that's what they suggest.

Comment: @antonio The article is a little vague and certainly misleading.  A quick google leads me to believe the Wiretap Act referenced is a federal law.  As a layman, I'd assume their ruling only pertains to the federal law, but many states have laws on recording audio as well, so I think you're advise is not good and if you want to know for sure a consulting a lawyer would be best.

Comment: Sorry, but no. Do not give them anything. Head to a lawyer and/or police. Giving someone fake information is encouraging counter-action. Don't do it.